# button image naming for many devices (Retina & Non-Retina)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

this is a simple question but can't find any answer describing how to do this, everything is informative and overviews
my app will work on iphone 4s, 5, 6 & 6+

i have a button image, and as i knew, it must be sized as following (Width):

- @1x: 320 ip 4s,5
- @1x: 375 ip 6
- @1x: 414 ip 6+
- @2x: 640 ip 4s,5
- @2x: 750 ip 6
- @3x: 1242 ip 6+

Ok, now how to name those images and how to add them to xcode project so that IOS detect according to the device type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the image to Images.xcassets. There you can set it as an iPhone/iPad/Mac image, which will automatically generate you the 1x 2x 3x etc. fields. To do this, just select the image that you have added right click in the inspector, then select the options that you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, was trying to do so, just figured out that i was adding the images once in the asset and other times in the project navigator,

Answer (score 4):

You could use the assets catalog, it is made for this. Find more in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/Recipe.html).

Comment: This is the way to go. Name them however you want, even photo123.png, and assign them to their respective slots in the asset catalog, all together as an image set.
The name of the asset("YellowCar", for example) will be the one you'll use in code.

Comment: Thanks @Zil, all fine now !